# Cannot connect Data Gateway to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to authenticate with my azure SQL database which is on private endpoints through Oauth authentication , but it fails and when I try using basic authentication it gets success , the data source is created and connected to the virtual network gateway. Why is my Oauth is not working . This is the weird error which I am facing is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjQuf.png)

Can anyone guide me on this and help me understand how Oauth works

Thank You,
gmp

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure Portal go under Power Platform and you will find the Power BI connection:

[image]

Click on this button and a new Power BI will be created and the connection to it will be created out of the box as well.

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot use this approach as my Database is on private endpoints so Power Bi will give error while conencting

Comment: You created the private end point and the Data network gateway. Of course you can connect to it. Why you shouldn't connect?

Comment: Can you try my approach and tell me where it fails?

Comment: I did try but I get instance specific error as I have denied my public access for azure sql server

Comment: I will try at home tonight

Comment: Did you get any chance to try ?

Comment: No, sorry... no time for now

Comment: @gmp, have you removed the URL to the guide?

Comment: yes, I have just edited a little bit

Comment: I mean, if I recall right there was a link to a guide with a step by step list of operations to put in place. I don't see it now

Comment: https://www.datahai.co.uk/power-bi/connecting-power-bi-to-azure-sql-database-using-private-endpoints/ - This was the link

Comment: dammit, I have a problem at the step "Create VNet Data Gateway in Power BI Service". Basically my Microsoft Authenticator enters in an infinite loop and I cannot login any more into Power BI. Sorry, I cannot reproduce the issue